# How to query multi SQL asynchrously?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I'm building webapp with nestjs and typeorm,

i wonder what does the code below actually do?

```
const r1 = await this.connection.query(sqlA)
const r2 = await this.connection query(sqlB)
```

Is it query sqlA, get result, and then query sqlB,get result in a synchrous way?

i want to query multi sql asynchourously,

```
const  _q1 = this.connection.query(sqlA)
const  _q2 = this.connection.query(sqlB)
const r1 = await _q1
const r2 = await _q2
```

is this way correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That way seems correct to me. This is because you call both of the `query` functions first, which returns promises, which are then after awaited for.

The first script goes in the order "call query function" -> "await resolution" -> "call another query function" -> "await resolution."

You can use `Promise.all` to call multiple Promises in parallel. This assures the result you're striving for.

```
const [r1, r2] = Promise.all([this.connection.query(sqlA), this.connection.query(sqlB)])
```